# gRPC "any" packing: No instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that ShopData conforms to Message

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc-java

I'm making a game with a custom server solution written in java that communicates with the game client using gRPC.

I'm attempting to pack a message (`ShopData`) into an "any" object, but it's saying `no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that ShopData conforms to Message`

As you can see I have a `GameNetworkEvent` message that contains a type flag and an "any" type payload.

I am building a `ShopData` payload then am attempting to pack it into the "any" `eventPayload` field. However the error seems to imply that `ShopData` isn't a message? I don't get how that can be, since it's an auto-generated class from my protobuf message definition

[protobuf to code mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcoQW.png)

## Relevant protobuf definitions

```
message GameNetworkEvent {
  enum Type {
    START = 0;
    SHOP = 1;
    BRAWL = 2;
    CHAT = 3;
  };
  Type eventType = 1;
  google.protobuf.Any eventPayload = 2;
}

message ShopData {
  int32 gold = 1;
  repeated UnitData units = 2;
}

message UnitData {
  string name = 1;
  int32 attack = 2;
  int32 health = 3;
  int32 cost = 4;
  bool isUpgraded = 5;
}
```

## Message instantiation

```
FromBeyondProto.ShopData shop =
        FromBeyondProto.ShopData.newBuilder()
                .addAllUnits(generateRandomShop(10))
                .setGold(10)
                .build();

FromBeyondProto.GameNetworkEvent response =
        FromBeyondProto.GameNetworkEvent.newBuilder()
                .setEventType(FromBeyondProto.GameNetworkEvent.Type.SHOP)
                .setEventPayload(Any.pack(shop))
                .build();
```

Comment: Could you also provide the UnitData definition please ? Also could you tell us where you can see the error ? I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Including part of the exception with stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: Edited to include those items

Comment: There is no stack trace- it is simply an error shown in the IDE on the the `.setEventPayload(Any.pack(shop))` line, specifically the `Any.pack(shop)` part. The specific part with the error should be visible in the linked image